# What happened to Sanji in Zou?

Tags: one-piece

The current situation of Sanji has not been made clear so far in the manga. The following is a summary of the pointers.

1. Sanji is the only person in the SH crew who is wanted Alive and not Alive/Dead.
2. His bounty has increased only by a 100 million Berries (to 177m berries ) which suggested that he was involved in any earth shaking event at Zou.
3. Nami is seen crying when she says to Luffy, "I'm sorry about Sanji" and there is nothing added on to it.
4. Brook says, "I'm so sorry about what happened to Sanji san. I can't even face you right now".
5. Strangely Luffy and crew are not at all worried about Sanji and don't feel obliged to go to his aid.
6. In the last seen image of Sanji he is seen tacking cannon balls from some ship and before that he defeats the Kaido crew pirate Sheepshed.

Considering the above, I like to know some plausible theories on the current condition of Sanji.

Comment: I assume Sanji was mad to Usopp's new bounty, left a letter to the other SHs that he is sneaking onto Jack's ship which attacking the marines to ruin Jack's plan and get a higher bounty of it.

Answer (score 3):

Sanji was taken from Zou by Capone Bege as per Big Mum's instructions, and invited to his own wedding, a diplomatic marriage between Sanji, the third son of the Vinsmoke family and Purin, the 35th daughter of the Charlotte (Big Mum) family.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: After reading the A&M rules and a few related questions, it would appear that I am not violating the "back your sources" rule as this is a speculation question, which appears to be allowed (see [Is a question that asks about a future event on-topic?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/)). Either way, my answer is the following:**

Knowing that One Piece is a Shōnen Manga (Main characters not dying easily is one of the trends) and that Sanji is fairly popular, here's what I can come up with:

My best candidate:

- Sanji broke his leg(s) with one too many `Diable Jambe`

  - Will probably have a *Miraculous Recovery* later on

Other possibilities:

- Sirens/Mermaids saved him when the ship fell in pieces, current location unknown.
- Temporarily Dead

In the unlikely case that Sanji is dead, here is what could have happened:

- A Kraken (or other *Mysterious Being From The Sea*) finished him
- One of the Kaido crewmen escaped and wanted revenge
- Ate a devil fruit and drowned.
- (Comical) Ate a devil fruit, got rescued by a mermaid, but died of nosebleed.

To answer point #5, Luffy believes in Sanji. Following the Shōnen archetype, when the main character says it'll be okay, it'll be okay. If sanji broke a leg, he'd probably crack a joke about having rubber bones, or something.

Comment: stating that you have to violate a rule doesn't make the violation acceptable

Comment: I did more research and corrected my statement.

Comment: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-future-events-releases

Comment: That is not the same question. see http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2483